# Identifying linux process/service calling kernel API

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, hook

I have a pretty abstract question regarding the kernel on linux systems.
I've been trying to understand whether it is possible or not to identify a process or a service that uses a certein system call **without recompiling** the kernel.

To be more specific, I would like to know if it is possible to get the pointer to the executable file calling a specific system call (which I'm already hooking), only via writing a kernel module, and inserting it to the kernel.

So, is it possible? And if it is, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:
use the macro "current" (refrencing task_struct) 
the following line of code is gives the pid of the currenty running process that uses the module
"current->pid"